# How to fix leaking PVC fitting?

Tags: leak, water-pressure, pvc

I screwed up. I'm usually pretty good with PVC. I used the approved cleaner and primer, and Weld-On 705. I've done this dozens of times.

But here's where I screwed up: one part was a threaded bushing: 1" glue to ½" NPT. I made the mistake of turning in a petcock before the glue cured (nominal 20 minutes).

All the other ~20 glued joints are fine under pressure, but this one bushing is slowly dripping from two or three spots.

I **really** don't want to re-do the entire assembly, which is what it will take to replace this one bushing.

My spouse suggested a hose clamp. I thought of using a hypodermic needle to squirt some additional 705 around the spot where the bushing meets the "T" fitting. Either of these have merit? Any other ideas?

Comment: You probably have to redo it. Can you cut into a piece near the the leaking fitting to replace it but still keep most of the pieces you have already assembled?

Comment: With two splices and a new "T" and bushing, I can do it. But the leaking has slowed considerably, and it's not a particularly sensitive environment (cement floor), so I'm going to continue to monitor it, rather than throw a bunch of plastic in the landfill.

Answer (score 4):

The hose clamp is right out.  All you'll do is crack something -- if you're lucky, right away.

Likewise trying to inject PVC cement (705) is not a good idea.  Even if you manage to plug the leaks, the majority of the joint is compromised.   It will eventually fail, and the law practically says it will fail 2 hours after you've left for a 2 week vacation, etc. (^_^)

PVC is super easy to repair or replace, and hacksaws are cheap too.  If it's a particularly difficult section of pipe, consider installing one or two [unions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piping_and_plumbing_fittings#Union), to make the repair easier.

Go ahead and rebuild that section properly.

Comment: My problems are:

1. environmental: I don't want to bring new plastic into the world, and don't want to put more plastic in landfills.

2. cost: I'm living very simply, and I'd rather put the money from even these simple parts into other things.

3. effort: I've got six baby goats and 12,000 seed starts in the greenhouse to care for.

The leak has slowed, and I'm going to monitor it. I don't get off the farm much, and can't remember my last vacation...

(Too bad this site shares Faceplant's hatred of line breaks. I had to copy line breaks and paste them here to format this comment.)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want self fusing silicone tape.  Dry it.  Wrap it.  Pressure test it.  Done.